# Can you increase the span of a window?

Tags: vim-windows

Let's say I have a window layout like below:

```
[1][2]
[3..3]
```

And I want to expand window 2 to look like this:

```
[1][2]
[3][2]
```

So window 2 will now be full height

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by moving window 2 rightwards ([`<C-W><S-L>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#CTRL-W_L) or [`:wincmd L`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Awincmd)):

- Initially, with focus on window 2:

  [image]
- `:wincmd L`:

  [image]

To get back to the original arrangement from here, move window 3 downwards: focus on window 3, then [`<C-W><S-J>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#CTRL-W_J) or `:wincmd J`.